# How do i place a block using mc.ThePlayer?

Tags: java, minecraft

I've tried using

```
mc.thePlayer.sendQueue.addToSendQueue(new C08PacketPlayerBlockPlacement(new BlockPos(mc.thePlayer.posX, mc.thePlayer.posY, mc.thePlayer.posZ)));
```

But it gives out the error:
`'C08PacketPlayerBlockPlacement(net.minecraft.item.ItemStack)' in 'net.minecraft.network.play.client.C08PacketPlayerBlockPlacement' cannot be applied to '(net.minecraft.util.BlockPos)'`

What would the packet be to place a block? and how do i place a specific block under my player?

Comment: The message you're getting seems pretty self-explanatory: you're calling a function that wants an `ItemStack` as an argument, but you passed it a `BlockPos` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The server calculates the position itself.

In order to place a block programatically, you need to send a interaction packet, clicking the block to place the block on. The interaction manager has abstractions for this (might not be called interaction manager on forge :P).